# class instance lost when using a class method stored as an object attribute

Tags: javascript, typescript

We have two typescript class. On of them define a method as an object argument then transmitted in another class.

```js
class MyService {
    public options: { [key: string]: any };

    constructor() { }

    public upload(file: File): void {
        const parallelHasher = new ParallelHasher('/public/md5_worker.js');

        this.options = {
            concurrency: 1,
            autoUpload: true,
            hashMethod: parallelHasher.hash // HERE
        };

        const uploadService = new UploadService(this.options);
        this.uploadsProgress = uploadService.start(file)
    }
}


class UploadService {
    constructor(public options: any) { }

    public async start(file: File): Promise<void> {
        const hash = await this.options.hashMethod(file);

        this.proceed(file, hash);
    }

    public proceed(file: File, hash: string): void {
        // do something
    }
}
```

We encounter an error when `UploadService.start()` is called due to the hash method of the third party:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at parallel_hasher.js:25
```

Here is the relevant part in third party code:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var ParallelHasher = (function () {
    function ParallelHasher(workerUri) {
        this._queue = [];
        this._ready = true;
        var self = this;
        if (Worker) {
            self._hashWorker = new Worker(workerUri);
            self._hashWorker.onmessage = self._recievedMessage.bind(self);
            self._hashWorker.onerror = function (err) {
                self._ready = false;
                console.error('Hash worker failure', err);
            };
        }
        else {
            self._ready = false;
            console.error('Web Workers are not supported in this browser');
        }
    }
    ParallelHasher.prototype.hash = function (blob) {
        var self = this;
        var promise;
        promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            self._queue.push({
                blob: blob,
                resolve: resolve,
                reject: reject,
            });
            self._processNext();
        });
        return promise;
    };
    return ParallelHasher;
}());
exports.ParallelHasher = ParallelHasher;
```

As you can see `_queue` is defined in the constructor and should be there when the `hash()` method tries to use it to push new element to queue.

By placing a debugger on the line with `var self = this;` in the third party's `hash` method, the value of `this` is equivalent to `this.options` in `MyService` class, instead of being `ParallelHasher`:

```
concurrency: 1,
autoUpload: true,
hashMethod: parallelHasher.hash
```

And indeed, there is no `_queue` in options, hence the error.

Somehow, the context of the third party's method call is set, not in the `ParallelHasher` instance but in the `options` object.

I don't really understand why, and how to prevent this from occuring.

Comment: See how the code uses `.bind()` in the hasher for the `_receivedMessage` function? That's what you have to do. JavaScript methods have no intrinsic binding to objects unless you force them to.

Comment: So `= parallelHasher.hash.bind(parallelHasher)`

Comment: Yes it works. Just to understand for next time, calling the hash just after defining the class instance: `const parallelHasher = new ParallelHasher('/public/md5_worker.js'); parallelHasher.hash(file);`  works and it then doesn't wait context. Why does it loose binding context after having been passed inside the options object?

Comment: It doesn't *lose* binding context: there **is no binding context**.  JavaScript doesn't work that way. The value of `this` in a function is determined by how a function is called (or, if it's been created by `.bind()`, by the parameters to that function).

Comment: [See this older question for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library's `parallelHasher.hash` method isn't bound to `this`, so when you pass the method itself, it loses its `this` pointer. Instead, in your options, you can create an anonymous function, so that the library method keeps its `this` context and you don't have to modify the library itself.

```
        this.options = {
            concurrency: 1,
            autoUpload: true,
            hashMethod: (blob) => {
                return parallelHasher.hash(blob);
            }
        };
```

Here's some docs that are worth reading to better understand what's going on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind